# Why are the links not working on my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I know this is sort of a please debug my code question, but I really don't know whats going on here.

I just added the content to this page and now none of the external or internal links will work (eg you click on them and nothing happens).  The Mega menu drop down works fine and I can click on links on it, but the links in the text dont work, and neither do any on the sidebars

Here is the page that is causing the problems

http://www.cookingisfun.ie/cookery-courses/course-details/101618/Guest-Chef-Diana-Kennedy-at-Kerrygold-Ballymaloe-Litfest

here is a similar page that has no issue.

http://www.cookingisfun.ie/cookery-courses/course-details/101364/Guest-Chef-Lilly-Higgins

I can click the Back to CourseList button which I Can't on the first.

This is not just a problem with my machine, I have tried from another machine and an Iphone with same result.

I can't see any javascript errors but I assume it is something to do with the plugin that marks the links as external though that plugin works elsewhere on my site.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have some errors in your HTML code (wrong nesting of tags or something or you did not close a tag right). If I want to inspect the "Back to course button" with Firefox I get the following

[image: Firefox]

It seems that the `#content-blocks` div is empty. Also the source code view of your page underlines me some tags red:

[image: red tags]

Normally this means that there are some HTML errors. Here the output of the HTML validator: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cookingisfun.ie%2Fcookery-courses%2Fcourse-details%2F101618%2FGuest-Chef-Diana-Kennedy-at-Kerrygold-Ballymaloe-Litfest&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0